# PNG image ok on Photoshop but looks really weird on the web

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, resize

I am trying to add a header to our website using a PNG file. The original image is of a cushion and has a transparent background which I need to keep as the background of the website has a colour. I needed to make the image wider so changed the canvas size and saved as - it looks absolutely fine on Photoshop but when I upload it to Shopify the background is white and there are loads of weird orange and yellow lines coming out of the edge of the cushion - all around the edge like it's covered in spikes - I've tried re-doing the canvas size from the original image but not sure how to stop something happening when I can't see it on photoshop - does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Also - the images have already previously been uploaded to the site at the original dimensions with no problems.

Comment: H. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think this can be answered without access to the PNG image. Can you share it?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to contact shopify support.